# Flutter IOS Duplicate plugin key: SocialSharePlugin

Tags: flutter, facebook-social-plugins

I am using two different share plugins in my flutter project. One plugin `social_share_plugin` and other is `social_share` . Both are used to share content on social media. Due to limitation of one plugin i have to use both. But i am getting `'Duplicate plugin key: SocialSharePlugin'`error when i run the project on IOS device. it is working fine on android device.

```
 var s = await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebookLink(
                    quote: 'Meeting',
                    url: shareLink,
                  );
```

and other plugin is used like

```
await SocialShare.shareTwitter(
                      shareText,
                      hashtags: ["meetup"],
                      url: shareLink,
                      trailingText: '#meeting',
                    );
```

Comment: hi! were you able to find a solution? i have the same issue

Comment: No i am still having this issue...

Comment: Hi, How you implemented both plugin. I have faced a issue when use both provider in androidManifest.xml for both plugin.

Comment: Only issue was in facebook share. I personally used facebook sharer url for sharing on facebook.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is `social_share` uses the same class name as `social_share_plugin` (they both have `SocialSharePlugin`). To resolve this, I forked the social_share package and changed every instance of `SocialSharePlugin` to `SocialShare`, including the file names.

Here's my forked repo if you would like to use or view: https://github.com/kaarens93/social_share
(I have a lot of 'unresolved reference' errors that I'm still in the process of fixing but unless you want to build the package, you shouldn't run into any issues implementing into your project)

Comment: yep the duplicate plugin key error is gone and i'm able to use both packages

Answer (score 0):

I ended up remove SocialShare completely from the project, and use flutter_share_me and SocialSharePlugin. I found Social_Share_plugin is the only one that works with Ins (and Facebook). None of the other packages worked in this aspect. However, with version 0.4 of SocialSharePlugin you need add Facebook api token to your info.plist file since the FBSDK used by SocialSharePlugin requires this token since version 13+. This change was not documented by 0.4 SocialSharePlugin.